Can cells in a matrix be merged? (Something like colspan in HTML.)
I am trying to create readable LaTeX formulas on a Wikimedia page.
matrix and & are generally helpful to align symbols.
But in the following example I would like to align the plus signs in the last rows,
that are not present in the rows above.
\begin{matrix}
\mathrm{A}(n, k) & ~~=~~ & \sum_{i=0}^k \mathrm{B}(n-i, n-k) \cdot \binom{n}{i} \\
\\
\mathrm{A}(5, 3) & ~~=~~ & \sum_{i=0}^3 \mathrm{B}(5-i, 5-3) \cdot \binom{5}{i} \\
       155       & ~~=~~ & \mathrm{B}(5, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{0} ~+~ \mathrm{B}(4, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{1} ~+~ \mathrm{B}(3, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{2} ~+~ \mathrm{B}(2, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{3} \\
       155       & ~~=~~ & 40 \cdot 1 ~+~ 13 \cdot 5 ~+~ 4 \cdot 10 ~+~ 1 \cdot 10 \\
\end{matrix}


In the logic of an HTML table, the sums above would be in a cell with colspan="7".
Can this be done in LaTeX?

Use array.
In order to ease input, I (locally) define column types for display style material (type C) and for operations and relations (type O).
Setting \arraycolsep to zero lets TeX use its standard spacing.
Avoid ~+~ or, even worse, ~~=~~: they give useless spaces that make the formulas less readable.
The key for spanning columns is obviously \multicolumn.
I also add how I would typeset the thing. Find better names for \uA and \uB based on their meaning.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\uA}{\mathrm{A}}
\newcommand{\uB}{\mathrm{B}}


\begin{document}

\[
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\displaystyle}c}
\newcolumntype{O}{>{{}}c<{{}}}
\begin{array}{ c *{4}{ O C } }
\uA(n, k) &=& \multicolumn{7}{C}{\sum_{i=0}^k \uB(n-i, n-k) \cdot \binom{n}{i}} \\
\addlinespace
\uA(5, 3) &=& \multicolumn{7}{C}{\sum_{i=0}^3 \uB(5-i, 5-3) \cdot \binom{5}{i}} \\
\addlinespace
155       &=& \uB(5, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{0} &+& \uB(4, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{1} &+&
                \uB(3, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{2} &+& \uB(2, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{3} \\
\addlinespace
155       &=& 40 \cdot 1 &+& 13 \cdot 5 &+& 4 \cdot 10 &+& 1 \cdot 10 \\
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{aligned}
\uA(n, k) &= \sum_{i=0}^k \uB(n-i, n-k) \cdot \binom{n}{i} \\
\uA(5, 3) &= \sum_{i=0}^3 \uB(5-i, 5-3) \cdot \binom{5}{i} \\
          &= \uB(5, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{0} + \uB(4, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{1} +
             \uB(3, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{2} + \uB(2, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{3} \\
          &= 40 \cdot 1 + 13 \cdot 5 + 4 \cdot 10 + 1 \cdot 10 \vphantom{\binom{5}{0}}\\
          &= 155 \smash[b]{\vphantom{\binom{5}{0}}}
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}



The layout above is indeed what I wanted. Unfortunately this does not work in <math> tags on Wiki pages.

According to the help page it is "a subset of LaTeX", and produces SVG images on the server. MathJax is in the browser. I did not downvote, btw.

@Watchduck The key is “subset”. You might be able to get a (suboptimal) result without the \newcolumntype instructions and standard column specifiers.

Here's my solution for this particular case. What I do is, knowing that the terms above are longer, is to put them in boxes, measure those boxes, and then give those measurements to the boxes where I will place the content from below.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\def\boxitfirst#1#2{\setbox#1=\hbox{$#2$}}
\def\boxwd#1#2{\hbox to \wd#1\relax{\hfil$#2$\hfil}}

\boxitfirst0{\mathrm{B}(5, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{1}}
\boxitfirst1{\mathrm{B}(4, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{2}}
\boxitfirst2{\mathrm{B}(3, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{3}}
\boxitfirst3{\mathrm{B}(2, 2) \cdot \binom{5}{4}}


$$
\begin{matrix}
\mathrm{A}(n, k) & ~~=~~ & \sum_{i=0}^k \mathrm{B}(n-i, n-k) \cdot \binom{n}{i} \\
\\
\mathrm{A}(5, 3) & ~~=~~ & \sum_{i=0}^3 \mathrm{B}(5-i, 5-3) \cdot \binom{5}{i} \\
       155       & ~~=~~ & \copy0 ~+~ \copy1 ~+~ \copy2 ~+~ \copy3 \\
       155       & ~~=~~ & \boxwd0{40\cdot 1} ~+~ \boxwd1{13 \cdot 5} ~+~ \boxwd2{4 \cdot 10} ~+~ \boxwd3{1 \cdot 10}\\
\end{matrix}
$$

\end{document}




Off-topic, don't suggest $$ in LaTeX format, please

See Why is [ ... ] preferable to $$ ... $$?.
